# Auto Increase Quantities when the product name is same

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview and some field with row and cell. when i add a product into a DRV its okay but when i add the same product again the quantities not increase but its add a new row below.

Please help me how i can update quantities in DRV when i add a same product but not add a new row. its just change a quantities cell.

[image]